# ¿Cómo poder escalar las distintas densidades de hdpi a xxhdpi.?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo problemas con las dimensiones (*dimens*), si bien creo el recurso para cada parpeta en dimen(*hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi*,etc) mi problema es no se bien sacar las medicas de densidades, si bien en *hdpi*  *1dp* es = *1.5px* como saber cuando vales en sus siguientes densidades , para que todos mis recursos se acomoden a estas pantallas con las medidas reasisgnadas a partir de una sola variables como recurso.

Dejo imágenes para dar a conocer mejor mi problema, se ve pequeño al cambiar de densidad. A continuación solo las muestro en 2 densidades, ni hablar de como se verán en las otras, seguro mas pequeños.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que crear carpetas tanto para tus _Layouts_ como para tus imágenes que sería la carpeta _Drawables_... ejemplo: _layout-xxhdpi_ Si quieres mas  info visita la páginas oficial https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=es

Comment: eso si lo tengo claro , pero las medidas , de otros archivos como el tamaño de texto y todo eso , no puede escalar de esa manera

Comment: Puedes aplicar lo mismo para la carpeta _dimens_